# bootstrap-vue change the position of <b-modal>

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

By default `<b-modal>` shows on top of the page. When attribute `centered` is added to the tag. It is centered.

However, I would like to show the modal with a certain amount of gap under the top of the page.
The Modal is shown when the home page is opened.

**AppModal.vue**

```
<template>
<b-modal ref="thisModalRef" :modal-class="my-modal" size="lg" hide-header hide-footer no-close-on-backdrop hide-header-close>
    //...
</b-modal>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mymodal: ['mymodal']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideModal () {
      this.$refs.thisModalRef.hide()
    },
    showModal () {
      this.$refs.thisModalRef.show()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .mymodal > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    right: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

**AppHome.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    // omitted
    <AppModal ref="modalRef"></AppModal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppModal from './AppModal'

export default {
  components: {
    AppModal
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal: function () {
      this.$refs.modalRef.showModal()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.showModal()
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
// ommitted
</style>
```

**html source related to modal**

```
<div id="__BVID__16___BV_modal_outer_">
   <div id="__BVID__16" role="dialog" class="modal fade show d-block mymodal" style="padding-right: 15px;">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div tabindex="-1" role="document" aria-describedby="__BVID__16___BV_modal_body_" class="modal-content">
            <!---->
            <div id="__BVID__16___BV_modal_body_" class="modal-body">
               // ommitted
            </div>
            <!---->
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="__BVID__16___BV_modal_backdrop_" class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, `mymodal` class is correctly applied. But the div `.modal-dialog` does not have the css properties I give it.

**the real css properties found in dev tools**

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I tried adding a custom class to `<b-modal>` and style it. Nothing worked.
Please help.

Comment: @Sphinx thank you but it is still not working.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to put the modal into the specific position, below is my solutuon:

1. add specific class to `<b-modal>` by its props=`modal-class`
2. then add your styles into `myclass > div`

You can look into [the github (line#:176)](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/modal/modal.js), Bootstrap-vue will place one `div.modal-content`(including header/body/foot) into one div with class="modal-dialog" which is the direct child of root.

That is why above solution use the css selector = `.myclass > div`.

If you look into the dom tree: the structure of one bootstrap-vue modal will be:

one root div (myclass will be added into here) -> one div with modal-dialog -> one div with modal-content -> header/body/footer

Below is one sample: (*I put different background-color for modal-dialog, modal-content.*)

```js
app = new Vue({ //not vue, it is Vue
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myclass: ['myclass']
  },
  methods: {
    showModal: function(){
      this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.myclass > div {
  position:absolute !important;
  top: -10px !important;
  left: -10px !important;
  background-color:yellow !important;
}

.myclass > .modal-dialog > .modal-content {
  background-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add this to <head> -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

<!-- Add this after vue.js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <b-button @click="showModal">
      Open Modal
    </b-button>
  <b-modal ref="myModalRef" :modal-class="myclass" size="lg">
      <h2>Test</h2>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, +1. I can see yours works. it is still not working on my end. I have slightly different setup. My `<b-modal>` is wrapped in a `<AppModal>` component, which is used in another component. `myclass` correctly attached to the root tag of `<b-modal>` but its direct child doesn't have the style. In other word, `myclass > div` is not working for some reason.

Comment: @MinjunYu, it doesn't matter what is the parent for `<b-modal>`, it probably caused by different version. You can open your web developer, then check the dom tree for `<b-modal>`, finally apply appropriate css selector. or you can add the html into the question, we can help you from there.

Comment: @MinjunYu `.myclass > .modal-dialog > .modal-content` this one also doesn't work?

Comment: No this one also doesn't work. I have put the related html source and vue components. Thank you!

Comment: @MinjunYu, I saw your html source, it is almost same as mine. May I know where you define the css? in one global css file or in current view with `<style>`?

Comment: @MinjunYu, it should be caused by [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). add `!important` should be able to fix the current issue you met. check the updated.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
<b-modal
    body-class="modalcart"
    ref="addToCart"
    id="addToCarModal"
    hide-footer
    hide-header
>
<b-container class="text-center modal-product-content">
  <img class="modal-image" src="~/assets/images/add-to-cart.png" alt=""/>
```

and:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
/deep/ .modalcart {
  font-family: 'poppins-bold';
  /deep/ .modal-product-content {
    padding: 3rem;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    /deep/ .modal-image {
      height: 150px;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      }
    }
  ...
  }
  </style>
```

and work! thanks
Keep in mind that not work without **body-class** and /deep/
I use node-sass, vue 3, vue-loader 15

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with something like `margin-top: 100px`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the `@media` breakpoint of Bootstrap. Then, in `<style>` you just override it.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .modal-dialog {
        margin: .5rem auto;
    }
}
```