# How to overwrite the vue-bootstrap styles in b-modal

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I tried to change the background-color in b-modal -> in .modal-header using `bootstrap-vue`. But the vue doesn't see my styles and I don know why :/
here is the code. I follow by answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989845/bootstrap-vue-change-the-position-of-b-modal)

HTML:

```
b-modal(id="card-1" title="CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO"  :modal-class="myclass" header-text-variant="light")
```

VUE

```
export default {
    data: {
   myclass: ['myclass']
 },
```

}

CSS

```
.myclass > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal-header {
  background-color: #da2228 !important;
  color: white;
}
```

But I still doesn't see the results. Modal header is white. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're probably using a `scoped` style tag in your `.vue` file.
If you are, then you need to use a [deep-selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) to properly target the subcomponent.

The selectors are `/deep/`, `>>>` or `::v-deep`.
In the below example i use `/deep/`, but the others should work for you as well.

You can also use the `header-class` prop on `b-modal` to directly add the class to the header if you wish.

```html
<template>
  <b-modal header-class="my-class">
    <template #modal-header>Header</template>
    Hello
  </b-modal>

  <b-modal modal-class="my-second-class">
    <template #modal-header>Header</template>
    Hello
  </b-modal>
</template>

<style scoped>
/deep/ .my-class {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

/deep/ .my-second-class > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal-header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. It;s working! I spent many hours on this case, completely paying no attention for this `scope` in css. Than for that.

Comment: A year later and you my friend @Hiws are still a savior!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use **content-class="your-class"** in the vue bootstrap modal.

```
<b-modal id="myModal" content-class="your-class" title="BootstrapVue">
    Body Content
</b-modal>
```

Or else it is difficult to style the modal cuz the normal **class=""** does not apply to the code.